# crop gif image using libMagick

Tags: image, image-processing, crop, rmagick

i am trying to crop a gif image using the libMagick.so library.

```
./convert --version 
Version: ImageMagick 6.2.8 03/31/08 Q16 file:/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.2.8/doc/index.html
```

using the following command:

```
convert img.gif -crop 91x68+6+116 out.gif
```

the out.gif image gets crop, but not re sized. i get the same image size while all of it is transparent except the 91 pixels starting at 6 pixels from the left point and 68 pixels starting 116 pixels from the top.

how can i make the convert command crop and leave only the cropped part as the output image.
by the way, when my output image is jpg, i get the expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the [`-repage`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#repage) option for GIF files:

```
convert img.gif -crop 91x68+6+116 -repage 0x0 out.gif
```

The problem is that GIFs can contain multiple images (of different sizes) when they're animated so cropping just affects one of the images while leaving the overall GIF canvas size untouched. Using `0x0` for the canvas size is an easy shortcut to make ImageMagick figure out how big the image should be:

> A given a canvas size of zero such as **'0x0'** forces it to recalculate the canvas size so the image (at its current offset) will appear completely on that canvas.

Comment: well, i tried your idea, and it partly worked. i find out that when i use convert img.gif -crop 91x68+6+116! out.gif i get the result i want, can you explain why , please

Comment: @Oded: What does "partly worked" mean? And the geometry argument format is documented here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry